# How to implement multithreading or multiprocessing of a request

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, multiprocessing

I'm looking to implement multithreading or multiprocessing of `request` objects.

My code is below:

```
def validate(testurl):
    json_d = {"task_id": "user_uid","data": {"document1":testurl}} 
    response = requests.post("https://example.net.com/document",headers=headers,json=json_d)
    my_data1 = response.text
    with open("testurl.txt","a+") as file:
        file.write(my_data1)
    my_data = json.loads(my_data1)
    result = {'bool_value':my_data['data']}
    return result
```

Is there a way to multithread or multiprocess a Pandas `apply()` function for more than 5000 urls?  For example:

```
df['res'] = df['testurl'].apply(validate)
```

Should I be using this below?

```
from joblib import parallel, delayed
```

Comment: Have you tried `threading` module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use swifter or dask for doing this. you can refer to https://gdcoder.com/speed-up-pandas-apply-function-using-dask-or-swifter-tutorial/

```
df['res'] = df['testurl'].swifter.apply(lambda x: validate(x))
```